# What is a Lymph Node Collection

Tags: cancer, terminology, tumors, ct-scans, lymph-nodes

I'm looking at my results from a C/T I had a year ago, because my doctor wants to get another since my lymph node is still enlarged. When I looked at the results I saw

> The right axillary region shows small bone lymph node collection measuring 2.1 cm x 1 cm collectively.

When these results came back, my doctor said everything looked fine. In the little research that I've done it looks like anything over 2 cm is cause for concern, but that was specifically about lymph nodes. So my question is, what is a lymph node collection, or even more specifically what is a bone lymph node collection. Is that different than a single lymph node? What is the normal size range?

Comment: Welcome to Health SE :-). I edited the last part of your question, because we can't comment whether a result is good or bad (or not too bad) - this would constitute personal medical advice, which is off-topic. We can, however, provide terminology clarification as well as give some "normal" ranges provided in scientific literature. I hope that you don't mind the change and I also hope that all goes well at your next doctor's appointment.